# Android Kotlin App crash after leaving a fragment that receives a callback from an API, when the callback didn't finish

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, navigation-drawer, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using retrofit2 and coroutines, I have a fragment A and B. I made the callback to fill a recyclerView at fragment B but if the user goes back to fragment A before the callback is finished, the app crashes because there is no B fragment to receive the data.
Of course, I can disable the back button until I receive the data from the callback, but I'm sure there is a better solution.
I found a navController class removeOnDestinationChangedListener, but I'm not sure how to use it or if it may help me with this problem.
Any Ideas?

Comment: How do you make your callback? You should be cancelling that callback when your fragment is destroyed.

Comment: coroutine cancellation is cooperative - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative

Comment: I was not cancelling the job at  onStop() event, I will add the solution below, however I'm still thinking there is a better and more elegant solution, any idea will be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

main declarations inside the Fragment:

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentShowCustomerBinding
var process: Job? = null
var productHistory: ArrayList<ProductHistory> = arrayListOf()
val producthistoryAdapter: ProductHistoryAdapter = ProductHistoryAdapter(arrayListOf())
```

This is how I call the service:

```
private fun loadCustomerActivity() {
    process =
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            MainService.getCustomerOrders(customer.documentNumber, 1)
            { customerActivity ->
                productHistory = customerActivity
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    binding.progressBarCustomerPurchaseHistory.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    binding.recyclerViewProductHistory.let {
                        producthistoryAdapter.loadCustomerhistory(productHistory)
                        producthistoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and this how I cancel it just in case the user get out from the fragment before I get the customer history:

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    process?.cancel()
}
```